# Why does Myanmar have significantly more trouble with democratic stability and its ethnicities than India?

Tags: india, myanmar

## Background

Both [Myanmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myanmar) and [India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India) have numerous ethnic groups within their societies. India has [countless numbers of ethnic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Asian_ethnic_groups#List_of_ethnic_groups_on_the_basis_of_language) within their society, and they manage to have a stable democracy.  While yes, there is discrimination between different groups, it has not resulted in a total government break down and seizure by the military, or genocide.

Myanmar, on the other hand, has [much less ethic diversity](https://www.cia.gov/the-world-factbook/countries/burma/#people-and-society), yet seems to be [intolerant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racism_in_Asia#Myanmar) toward several ethnic groups, especially the [Rohingya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rohingya_genocide).  Both India and Burma were under British rule as one colony and were exposed to the systems they set up there...yet India did not have a sustained military coup(s) that Myanmar had and currently has, nor did they carry out genocide like Myanmar did.  The numerous similarities and proximity of India and Myanmar led me to ask...

## Question

Why is Myanmar less democratically stable and more ethnically intolerant than India?

Comment: Those seem like 2 separate questions. As Don Hosek points out, India fractured in two over religious lines almost immediately after gaining independence. I'm also not sure it's a fair comparison on the democratic stability front. Myanmar has been a solid military dictatorship since 1962 – is a democracy that collapsed once and never recovered unstable, or just non-existant?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Muslims of India might beg to differ with your assessment. Remember that post-colonial India originally comprised what's now India, Pakistan and Bangladesh. The [partition of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_India) was a significantly bloody event which resulted in possibly as many as two million deaths as well as the displacement of ten to twenty million people. There are continued ethnic tensions in India with Hindu nationalism being a particular concern not to mention the continued international conflicts between India and Pakistan (and to a lesser extent Bangladesh).

Comment: That is irrelevant as it ignores two things - [the British deliberately engineered the partition](https://qz.com/india/1684372/why-the-india-pakistan-partition-suited-the-british-empire) for geopolitical reasons, and India continues to have a huge number of muslims (even more than some muslim nations) and has continued to uphold the democratic values it carefully cultivated.

Answer (score 2):

First, "democracy" and Myanmar are not an obvious match.  Any system in which the army has a reserved number of seats in Parliament starts out with a democratic deficit.  Doubly so when the country had been essentially under martial law for the last 50-60 years and only allowed some level of civilian controls recently.

Second, their circumstances are not as similar as you might think.  Trying to figure out what drives Burmese army participation, it turns out that they have on occasion been under foreign threat.

In the 1950s, KMT forces from Taiwan, with US backing, [invaded Burma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatmadaw#Kuomintang_invasion) to attack Communist China.

Finally, India is not as strife-fee as all that.  The [Gujarat Riots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_Gujarat_riots) saw 2000 Muslims lynched (after a previous torching of Hindu pilgrims in a train).  Who was that state's Chief Minister at the time, and who got accused - and acquitted - of doing little to stop things?  Why, Modi, of course.

Answer (score -2):

If ethnic composition is the only parameter for the stability of democracy then many more democracies are in a much greater disadvantage. The stability depends on the quality of Leadership and Institution. Indian Military forces are lead by professional soldiers and well isolated from politics. The resiliance of India is also defined by the outlook and quality of leaders particularly the leaders during independence.

Comment: I would add **luck** to that. Some countries have bad governance in good times and recover. Some countries have bad governance in difficult times and spiral downwards.

Answer (score -2):

Well, the main reason is how aggressively pro-unity Indian culture is. Not that that is necessarily a bad thing, unless your life happens to be mutually exclusive to it.

Also, Myanmar is not necessarily intolerant, in the sense it hates other groups by default. I don't really know.

What it does have is extremely contradictory goals. The media likes portraying the military as the aggressors, but really, everyone is (including the military).

Basically, many minority groups in Myanmar, be it ethnic, religious, political, other, or a mix, really want independence.

Meanwhile, the military (and quite a lot of other humans) really *don't* want independence.

This makes Myanmar, what can only be called a hot mess, with no solution in sight.

Every side is clever enough to know the other sides will never change their mind with peaceful measures. Virtually every side is not willing to give up on their goals.

Meanwhile, the media portrays the problem as being easily fixable if only a few bad actors were removed. This is just not true, as the situation is unresolvable and there is no hope,